# jquery carousel doesn't display on browser but displays on dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jcarousel

I have a jQuery slider (carousel) on my index page that when I add in it Dreamweaver, it seems to check fine and it functions properly even when I preview in the browsers.

When I upload my site to the server ([see here](http://www.waldenservices.com)), everything works except the slider. There is an empty blank space with my left/right arrows, but that's all.

I ran the console in Chrome, and it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'featureCarousel' (index):64
(anonymous function) (index):64
n jquery-1.7.min.js:2
o.fireWith jquery-1.7.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery-1.7.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.C
```

Which snippet of code should I post here so you can have a better understanding?

I need to mention that, for the main frame of my site, I am using a responsive grid system that also needs .js to work. Do you think there is a conflict of some sort here?

Comment: are you importing the `Jquery` library BEFORE the others?

Comment: I am really not positive on that. like I said i'm new at this and I did it as "trial and error". My grid uses jquery 1.7.min.js, modernizer 2.5.3.js, resposivegridsystem.js and selectivizr-min.js

Comment: @user3147144 You are importing jQuery before other script that requires it So you are good there!

Comment: my carousel uses jquery.featurecarousel.min.js, featurecarousel.js and jquery 1.7.min.js

Comment: @user3147144 I found your problem! I will post an awser

Comment: so when I go on developer on chrome it gives me that error "my object has no method" and I am not sure what that means...I should have practiced before I jumped into this. I really need this to work. Do you guys need anything from me to help me solve this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are actually importing jQuery twice! Once in the `<head>`:

```
<script src="scripts/js/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

**AND** once on the bottom of the page:

```
<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if necessary -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

You need to remove the one at the bottom of the page. Please let me know if you have any questions and I will answer them the best I can!

Comment: I will go and try that! I'll post here if it worked on my end. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much! wow, I was obviously not looking at the big picture here. I didn't even realize I also added it to the bottom of the page. You're a God! I appreciate your help so very much!

Comment: Here I am again asking dumb questions (maybe) and I was wondering if you could take a look a this question and maybe shed some light? thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002450/responsive-grid-not-adapting-to-screen-sizes-how-do-i-call-the-script

Comment: I will take a look when I get back from lunch.