# Responsive grid not adapting to screen sizes. How do I call the script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I am back here again with another question for responsive grid systems. I have this website http://www.waldenservices.com that uses The Responsive Grid system with various columns, I have CSS codes for 1024, 768 and 480. I am definitely inserting the css scripts on the page but I am not sure of the jQuery/java code I need to make it work.

My questions are: What script do i need to call these css styles?

And, Does these help me to detect the screen size of the user? (I think web browser size is one is my biggest concern, as different users cannot see the whole page but have to scroll from side to side to even see the whole menu).
Any help or input is very appreciated, I really don't want to have to redesign this whole page.

Thank you guys!

Comment: jQuery/java??????i think you are a bit confused

Comment: yes, I am confused as I have been reading about this "Web adapting" thing and it makes me more confused than anything.

Comment: If it is adaptive, why do you have fixed pixel widths on elements? `body { margin : 0 auto; width: 1300px;` That is not how it should work. Where are the media queries for width?

Comment: some of my elements didn't seem to line up correctly when I tried to use percentage values when I viewed on browsers.

Comment: @user3147144 A tip: CSS files aren't *scripts*, they're *stylesheets*. :)

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers. I changed the width to "%" instead of "px" but now it affects my overall layout. I am not very concerned on Mobile resolutions but browsers mostly and since, I am new at programming I get confused easily.

Comment: @user3147144 You can try with some already-done grids, like in frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to call *script* (I don't know what you meant by it), you just need responsive stylsheet.

All you need:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .col-5 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

- `@media` is CSS `@` rule, used for media queries.
- `screen` means these styles are just for screens, not for printers, or for presentations.
- `(min-width: value)` and `(max-width: value)` are used to specify minumum or maximum screen size on which these styles will apply. You can combine `(min-width)` and `(max-width)`.

Whenever, if you have problems with coding responsive grid systems, you can start using a framework (e.g. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)).

Comment: such as here?'<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 769px)" href="/css/1024.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 481px)" href="/css/768.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="/css/480.css">'

Comment: Using multiple stylesheet `<link>`s as media queries are wrong. It makes many HTTP requests. :D

Comment: ok, bear with me please, what if I use different columns in different pages? I see you used the ".col-5" and set the width...but what if I have from 2-12 columns in some pages and not on others? (I know, you are probably starting to pull your hair out by now)

Comment: No need for it. Try with Bootstrap or Foundation, you'll see it works. `.col-5` is just an example class which gets media query styles. :)

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/05/29/useful-glossaries-for-web-designers-and-developers/

http://www.cssbasics.com/

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design

http://www.splio.com/responsive/

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/

http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: What about boilerplate? and when I use either of these frameworks, do I just "copy/paste" my already written code? :(

Comment: @user3147144 It is also possible. Something like https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/main.css (look at media queries part).

Comment: You don't use any framework blindly you read the docs and have some css and html chops behind you or you learn them. TeamTreeHouse.com teaches via video

Comment: thanks @zgood! appreciate you dropping by to help me out...yet again!